# Does somebody have a working sample of PHP session_set_save_handler?

Tags: php, mysql, session

PHP Version 5.1.6
All day trying..I'm breaking my head now... I understand it but can't make it work. I need to store the session data in a mysql database, cause we're balancing the request among 2 servers, so regular sessions wont work... I need to use this function ... session_set_save_handler ... and I cant make it work..any help greatly appreciated it.
Thank you !

Answer (score 3):

If you look at the [comments](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-save-handler.php#96305) on the PHP documentation page for `session_set_save_handler()`, you can see a full copy of a class that will store the session data into a database.

The basic database schema involves 3 columns: Session ID, Session Data, and Session Timestamp

The Session ID and Session Data are the critical ones, as PHP gives you both. Session ID is a random ID, and Session Data is a `serialize()`-like string that represents session data.

The timestamp is simply for you figuring out when to delete it.

I also have an old working copy of a Session Handler [here](http://github.com/chacha/Cha_Frame_Old/blob/master/system/objects/SessionHandler.core.php) in one of my old frameworks.

Answer (score 1):

Full script available at:

http://forums.devnetwork.net/viewtopic.php?t=23781